# How to pass JSONArry in an HTTP request?

Tags: java, android

I've tried to pass my `arraylist` to an API call. I got a response from the server, and after clearing the array list which I used to pass to the API call using the `clear()` method, I then added new data to the `arraylist`. Then I'm not able to call the API and I'm not getting the data.

Here is the code:

```
private class Add_Bid  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    JSONArray jArray;
    JSONObject js;
    String status, message;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Set Progress Dialog Text
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            try {
                JSONArray jsA = new JSONArray(bidArr);
                Log.e("bidArr1",":"+bidArr.toString());
                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                // postDataParams.put("name", "abc");
                postDataParams.put("userId", pref.getString("userId", ""));
                postDataParams.put("name", "");
                postDataParams.put("mobile", "");
                postDataParams.put("detailId", detail_id);
                postDataParams.put("currentBidCount", TotalBidCount);
                // postDataParams.put("count",count.getText().toString());
                postDataParams.put("adminId", pref.getString("admin", ""));
                postDataParams.put("wholesalerId", pref.getString("wholesaler", ""));
                postDataParams.put("retailerId", pref.getString("userId", ""));
                // postDataParams.put("bidNumber",nmbr.getText().toString());
                // postDataParams.put("bidAmount",100);
                postDataParams.put("bidDateTime", localTime);
                postDataParams.put("lat", latitude);
                postDataParams.put("long", longitude);
                postDataParams.put("location", address);
                postDataParams.put("device", prefdevice.getString("userId", ""));
                postDataParams.put("createdBy", pref.getString("userId", ""));
                postDataParams.put("BidArray", bidArr.toString());

                ArrayList<PairValues> paramss = new ArrayList<PairValues>();
                Log.e("bidding", "parameters=" + postDataParams);

                // paramss.add(new PairValues("secret", pref.getString("secret", "")));
                // paramss.add(new PairValues("token", pref.getString("token", "")));
                // paramss.add(new PairValues("mobile",pref.getString("mobile","")));

                paramss.add(new PairValues("password", pref.getString("password", "")));
                com.mis.appsendtoserver.sendtoserver.SendToServer server = new SendToServer();
                String response = server.SendToServerPost(postDataParams, Constants.API_ADD_BID, Bidding.this, paramss);

                Log.e("response ", "" + response);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                js = new JSONObject(response);

                // editor.putString("secret", js.getString("secret"));
                // editor.putString("token", js.getString("token"));

                // editor.apply();
                if (js.has("results")) {
                    jArray = js.getJSONArray("results");
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            if (js.getString("message").equals("Done.")) {
                Toast.makeText(Bidding.this, "Bidding Successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                customer_mob_number.setText("");
                bidding_table.removeAllViews();
                addHeading();
                Log.e("bidArr",":"+bidArr.toString());
                arr_status=1;
                // bidjsonArray= new JSONArray();
                clear(bidArr);
                // clearArr();
                Log.e("bidArr",":"+bidArr.toString());
                customers_name.setText("");
                currentCredit=0;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Bidding.this, js.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currentCredit=0;
                bidding_table.removeAllViews();
                addHeading();
                customer_mob_number.setText("");
                customers_name.setText("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // retailer_name.setText(pref.getString("name",""));
    }
}
```

How do I solve this issue?